# Логотип и ссылки в строку

Tags: html, css

Хочу чтобы логотип и ссылки были в одну строку.
Я хочу это сделать с помощью флексов или гридов.
как это сделать на моем примере?

```css
html,body{
   min-height: 5026px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

.container{
    width: 1060px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


header{
   
}

nav li{
}
nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
   
}



.main-navigation a{
   
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #626262;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}





#logo{
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata|Playfair+Display:400,400i,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" href="js/script.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="container">
    <header class="main-navigation">
            <h1 href="#" id="logo">minimø</h1>
        <nav>
        <ul>
            
            <li><a href="#">lifestyle</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">photodiary</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">music</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">travel</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>   
    
            </div>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="himg">
        <img src="img/himg.png" alt="" >
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

как должно выглядеть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*флоаты и инлайн блоки больше не юзаю*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прокачав свои скилы решил ответить на свой вопрос сам.

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}
.logo{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}


.menu{
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
}
li{
    margin-left: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
       <div class="logo">
           <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="">
           <span>Logo</span>
       </div>
       <ul class="menu">
           <li><a href="">home</a></li>
           <li><a href="">about</a></li>
           <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
           <li><a href="">Call</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
li{
  list-style: none;
}

header{
    position: absolute;
    height: 15vh;
 z-index: 10;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
 width: 80vw;
    left: 10%;
    background-color: #00a550;
}

nav.hMenu{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
nav.hMenu a{
    padding: 7px 1vw;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
}
nav.hMenu a:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

span.logo{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <span class="logo">minimø</span>
    <nav class="hMenu">
        <li><a href="index.html">Hello</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </nav>
</header>
```